# Removing unused heavy packages from vue.js

Tags: vue.js, xlsx, pdfmake

So recently I have been really wanting to speed up my website that is kinda heavy but when I built the app I noticed that I have 2 packages that are really heavy and I'm not using or at least I don't know whats using them.

The packages are pdmake.js and xlsx.js as you can see in the picture below:
[image]

I tried to uninstall them but it didn't work I also checked package.json and they aren't there so I'm really confused about these 2 specific packages. I also don't have any of these files in my js folder or any folder in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pdfmake.js` and `xlsx.js` are included by [AmCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/integrations/using-webpack/#Large_file_sizes)

They are fetched by browsers dynamically and only when needed - so the only downside is increased build time. If you are sure you do not need/use these - you can disable them through `vue.config.js`:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => 
  {
    config.externals = function (context, request, callback) 
    {
      if (/xlsx|canvg|pdfmake/.test(request)) 
      {
        return callback(null, "commonjs " + request);
      }
      callback();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using AmCharts so that makes sense. Ill do it and let you know if it worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the following error `Error while running task C:\Users\amng8\Google Drive\RUBY\Code\Ruby\app\client:build with message 'spawn vue-cli-service ENOENT'
 ERROR  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':`

Comment: It does not say which token is not expected.

Comment: Its the : token.

Comment: At `config.externals: function (context, request, callback)`

Comment: Sorry, please replace the colon with assignment operator.